# autocomplete jQuery UI com chamada AJAX não exibindo as apções

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Bem, estou tentando implementar o autocomplete do *jQuery UI* em meu código, mas de forma parcial ele não funciona, pois ele não exibe as opções abaixo do componente de *input*. Ele realiza de for correta a requisição, mas na hora de mostrar as opções na tela vem em branco. Tenho quase certeza que é a forma que estou mandando meu *JSON* para o atributo *source* do *plugin*.

Abaixo seguem os códigos:

**O Input**

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <input id="first-name" placeholder="Primeiro Nome" name="firstName" type="text" class="form-control"/>
</div>
```

**Codigo JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $("#first-name").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/auth/getCustomerAJAX",
                    type: "GET",
                    data: {
                        paramName: request.term
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                        alert(obj);
                        response(obj.firstName);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**O callback (Desconsiderar os NULL)**

```
[
{
"idCustomer":1,
"tenantId":null,
"birthDate":null,
"email":"joao.manolo@gmail.com",
"firstName":"j",
"gender":"\u0000",
"lastName":"Galao Bonin",
"document":null,
"customerPhone":null,
"passenger":null,
"customerAddress":null,
"observations":null,
"customerService":null
}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

ta faltando a parte do "select" amigo vou te mostrar um exemplo meu:

```
$('#cid_nome').autocomplete({                                                       // AUTOCOMPLETAR A PLACA DO VEICULO
        minLength: 2,                                                                   // TAMANHO MINIMO PARA AUTOCOMPLETAR
        source: function( request, response ) {                                         // ORIGEM DA INFORMAÇÃO                
            var obj = new Object();                                                     // NOVO OBJETO
            obj.maxRows = 10;                                                           // MAXIMO DE REGISTROS NO RETORNO
            obj.letra = request.term;                                                   // TERMO DA PESQUISA
            var data = custom.ajax(obj,'','../view/consultaCidade.php');                // CONSULTA EM BANCO
            response( $.map( data, function( item ) {                                   // FUNCAO RESPONSE 
                return {label: item.cid_nome+'->'+item.cid_estado,obj: item} }));       // RETORNO
        },                                                                              // FIM DA ORIGEM DOS DADOS
        select: function( event, ui ) {                                                 // PARAMETRO SELECT                                
            $( "#cid_nome" ).val( ui.item.obj.cid_nome );                               // PREENCHE RETORNO DA CONSULTA
            $( "#cid_cod_nome" ).val(ui.item.obj.cid_id);                               // PREENCHE RETORNO DA CONSULTA            
        }                                                                               // FIM DO PARAMETRO SELECT
    });
```

no autocomplete o select tem que ester preenchido com o que você tem no seu callback da sua consulta aos dados

Comment: Legal Maison! Só pode ser isso mesmo. Irei testar o mais breve possível e logo te passo o feedback.